# SVA syntax: Difference between ##1 a |-> b versus a |-> $past(b)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

What's the difference between these two expressions:

```
##1 a |-> b
```

versus

```
a |-> $past(b)
```

In the first one, will the value of `b` from the current cycle be used or from the next cycle?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the *overlapping* implication operator in both cases, the cycle that the LHS(antecedent) becomes true is the same cycle the RHS(consequent) starts. So in the first statement, Both `a` and `b` must be true in the same cycle. The `##1` just delays the whole operation by one cycle.

You might be thinking of the difference between *overlapping* and *non-overlapping*. For these simple properties, the following are equivalent:

```
a |-> b;
a |=> $past(b);
```

Comment: OK thanks. Follow-up question based on your explanation: Are these equivalent? a |-> $past(b)  v/s ##1 a |-> $past ... i think not, because I see them give different results in my tool. But then I thought, these have to be equivalent: ##1 a |-> $past(b) v/s a |-> $past(b,2) .. but these too give difference results

Comment: Remember what I said about overlapping implication.

Comment: Yes, based on your explanation I would expect a |-> $past(b) v/s ##1 a |-> $past to give equivalent results when used in a concurrent assertion (since one should just be a delayed version of the other, but essentially performing the same check). But this is not what I see with my formal tool. They give different results, the '##1' passes while the other one throws a violation. And when I ask the tool to show me a violation example, it just shows be 1 clock cycle worth info, which seems to tell me that its not seeing the assertion as a 2 cycle based one.

Comment: Maybe it seems like the tool has a trouble with 'a |-> $past(b)' because 'a' may be true for the very first cycle, at which time $past(b) is undefined. Then it makes sense why '##1 a |-> $past(b)' works fine.